# Translation needed in Lookup dialog search layout

Tags: lookup, related-list, lookup-filter, search-layout

I have a field in Account : Account Type.
For a particular set of users with language en_us this field is translated to : HCP/HCO Type
Now, in another related object of Account say Acct_child, Account lookup field Acct__c exists.
Now, while selecting a particular account from the lookup dialog, this HCP/HCO Type field appears, inside the lookup dialog search layout.  For this particular occasion I need it to be translated to HCP Type, instead of HCP/HCO Type. Is that possible using configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible using configuration. The label for a field can have translations for different langauges, but it will always be displayed the same across the application, no matter where the user is viewing it.